# Generic Model in Mobx State Tree?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I will have multiple "products" that have different "specs"

Examples

Products

- Cameras
- Laptop

Camera Specs

- Digital Camera Megapixels
- Brand
- Optical Zoom

Laptop Sepcs

- Brand
- Ram Size
- Operating System
- Number of CPU Cores
- Display Size
- Hard Drive Size

I will have 2 components

1. Filter Component
2. Search Results

The filter component will be a list of all the available filters for that product.

Search Results will be the results that come back as the user filters down the results and will show them some of the specs of each product found.

I am using Mbox State Tree and I have no clue how to store the "products" that are coming back from the server as each product will have different properties.

I could I guess maybe make a model for each type

```
  .model({
    id: types.identifierNumber,
    Brand: types.string,
    OpticalZoom: types.string,
    MegaPixels: types.string,
  })

  .model({
    id: types.identifierNumber,
    Brand: types.string,
    RamSize: types.string,
    Os: types.string,
    Cores: types.string,
    Display: types.string,
   HarddriveSize: types.string,
  })
```

but now I would not know how to access 2 different models in my components as it would be tied to these models.

I could make 1 huge model, but I am not crazy about this idea as many properties won't be used.

Another thing that I have to consider is that a user can then click on one of the results that will go to another page and show all the details. I would probably use the MST reference so gain access to it, what I would not be able to do if I make all separate models.

Any suggestions, to me I think I need more of a json or something more dynamic so I am not sure if MST is the right solution for this, but I am not an expert in it so I want to see if it can be used.

Comment: you can check about types.union. Ex: products: types.array(types.union(CameraModel, LaptopModel))

Comment: hmm interesting I guess I would have to do alot of "is" checks to see what type I am dealing with. The other way I was think of doing it was an Array of "Specs" and one field would be properyName and other would be "value" but I have not thought it out much yet. Will have to compare what is the better option.

Answer (score 2):

use `types.union(Camera, Laptop)`. category(or type) type key per each type. Then use views to get specific type.

```
const Camera = model({
  type: literal('camera')
});
const Laptop = model({
  type: literal('laptop')
});

const Data = model({
  products: array(union(Camera, Laptop))
})
.views( self => ({
  get cameras() {
    return self.products.filter( p => p.type === 'camera');
  },
  get laptops() {
    return self.products.filter( p => p.type === 'laptop');
  }
}))
```